# fatal:unable to update url base from redirection... can't solve it

Tags: java, git, github, gitlab

fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:
  asked for: https://gitlab.server.com/tech/project/tree/qa-456/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
   redirect: https://gitlab.server.com/users/sign_in
I am getting this error whenever I am trying to push my code in gitlab

Comment: I get it that the first url is wrong but How to fix the same in gitlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, this error means that the URL is wrong.  You've specified a URL for the UI, which can't be used as a Git remote.

First, check your remotes with `git remote -v` and find the remote with the bad URL (we'll pretend it's `origin`).  Then, do `git remote set-url origin https://gitlab.server.com/tech/project.git`.  That should be the correct URL based on your error message and then you should be able to push.

Note that if you're trying to push to a particular branch, the URL you're using doesn't change.  Just specify the proper branch name on the command line after the remote name.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I was on and off a vpn. I had to reset the remote url (`git remote set-url origin <url>`) with url from `git remote -v`